# Read between certain words and print out whats in between. (Python)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, file-io, readfile

Hello I am fairly new to python programming and i was wondering how I would be able to fix my code to allow me to only read in between two strings inside a normal text document. for example lets say i have the following

```
unimportant data  
unimportant data   
unimportant data 
... ... ...   
First string     #I want to print out starting from this line                     
Important data
Important data
Important data
Important data  
Last String       #Last line I dont want to print this line.
unimportant data  
unimportant data   
unimportant data 
unimportant data  
unimportant data   
unimportant data
```

So far I have been able to make a simple File I/O to read a single line.

```
data_file = open("test.txt", "r")

for line in data_file:
    if re.match("(.*)First String(.*)", line):
        print(line)
```

however this only prints out the First line.

Any tips or help would be much appericated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
go = False
start = "First string"
end = "Last String"

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == start: go = True
        elif line == end:
            go = False
            continue
        if go: print(line)
```

Instead of matching the whole line, if you were simply looking for a keyword:

```
go = False
start = "First string"
end = "Last String"

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if start in line: go = True
        elif end in line:
            go = False
            continue
        if go: print(line)
```

Comment: Okay this works great however I have another question for the string. Rather than trying to match a whole string how about just a key word in the string? So lets say I have 

unimportant word unimportant word keyword
important data 
important data
important Data
unimportant word key word

Comment: This works great! Thank you Ill see how more complex i can make it as i work further. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.dropwhile`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
def find_section(fle, start, end):
    from itertools import dropwhile
    with open(fle) as f:
        for line in dropwhile(lambda x: not x.startswith(start), f):
            if line.startswith(end):
                break
            yield line

for line in find_section("in.txt", "First String ", "Last string  "):
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
First string     #I want to print out starting from this line                     

Important data

Important data

Important data
```

Or combine takewhile and dropwhile:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile

def find_section(fle, start, end):
    with open(fle) as f:
        for line in takewhile(lambda x: not x.startswith(start),
                              dropwhile(lambda x: not x.startswith(end), f)):
            yield line
```

Or just use an inner loop:

```
def find_section(fle, start, end):
    with open(fle) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(start):
                yield line
                for _line in f:
                    if _line.startswith(end):
                        return
                    yield _line


for line in find_section("in.txt", "First string", "Last String  "):
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
First string     #I want to print out starting from this line                     

Important data

Important data

Important data

Important data
```

What ever condition you want to match just use it in the lambda, replacing the startswith logic and the same using the for loop